# Plot a function for different arguments

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have a function that I want to plot for several values of a parameter all within the same plot. For instance the function f defined as

```
f[a_,b_,c_,d_]:= a+Sin[b]*Exp[c]-d^4
```

If I now want to plot `f[a,1,2,3]` with respect to a from 0 to 1 I simply write

```
Plot[f[a,1,2,3],{a,0,1}]
```

But suppose I want to instead plot `f[a,b,2,3]` same as before for a from 0 to b/2 but now the parameter b takes on several values, say `b = 0,1,2,3,4` and so on. How can I do this all in the same plot (preferably with different colors on each curve corr. to the various b-values)?

Comment: What about something like: `Plot[Map[f[a,#,2,3]&,{0,1,2,3,4},{a,0,1}]]`?

Comment: I am voting to close this as "easy to find in the documentation" because one of the first examples in the `Plot` documentation page shows how to do this. See the last entry under Basic Examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] := a + Sin[b]*Exp[c] - d^4;

funs = f[a, #, 2, 3] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
Plot[funs, {a, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `Table` inside the `Plot` as well as `Evaluate`, like so (I did some formatting of the plot, which can be completely omitted)

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] := a + Sin[b]*Exp[c] - d^4
pltfnctn[xx_] := 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[f[a, b, 2, 3], {b, 0, xx, 1}]], {a, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   LineLegend[Table[b, {b, 0, xx, 1}], 
    LegendLabel -> "The parameter b"], Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

Then, we run

```
pltfnctn[4]
```

This results in

[image]

The resaon that I defined a function is that you can change the number 4 to anything really straightforwardly.